# El capitan cocoapods 0.38.2 can not find pod?

Tags: swift, cocoapods, osx-elcapitan

I have installed the El Capitan GM version today. I am trying to install a pod which name is `'libjingle_peerconnection', '~> 9514.2'`
In another mac which has a Yosemite OS can find the version. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by removing `.cocoapods` folder from the home directory. `.cocoapods` folder includes podspecs of the repos.

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me. Reinstall use below command:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Comment: You can check full description here https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3692

Comment: Same here, upgraded to El Capitan and got the message `-bash: pod: command not found`. Reinstalling like suggested solved it for me! +1